# AdView nots showing with ExpandableListView

Tags: android, expandablelistview, adview

i want to integrate an Admob ad with my android application. everything is working great but the ad banner is not showing! i dont know whats the probleme.
anyhelp plz
this is my code.
for activity_main.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#f4f4f4"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ExpandableListView
    android:id="@+id/lvExp"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<com.google.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-7203358988240052/2007826925"
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

For my Main_Activity.java i used :

```
    AdView adView = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
    adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a LinearLayout which uses the "eldest child first" approach. In your layout, you eldest child is the ExpandableListView (ELV) and despite you having specified that the height of the ELV should be wrapping it's content, it is still taking up the full screen space as there is enough content in the ELV to do this. Hence, there is no space for your AdsView to be displayed.

One option is to use the android:layout_weight attribute to distribute the available screen space between the different widgets. So, if you wanted your widgets to share the screen space such that the ELV gets 90% of the screen and the AdsView gets 10% of the screen, you can do something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#f4f4f4"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ExpandableListView
    android:id="@+id/lvExp"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="0dip" <!-- When you are using weights, set the height to 0 as the weight will control the height -->
     android:layout_weight="90" />

<com.google.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="10"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-7203358988240052/2007826925"
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

When you are using weights, you should set the height to zero as the weight will control the height in vertical orientation.

Just use whatever ratio you want. You can use 80/20 or 75/25 or whatever.

**EDIT:** I downloaded your app from the link you provided and ran the code. The first thing I noticed is that your AdView does take up space. Which means that the layout is fine - it's that you are not receiving any ad to show. So I looked around your code for a while and it immediately struck me that you are using the legacy Google Mobile Ads SDK. I know that this has been deprecated (please see https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/android-legacy/) which means that you cannot submit an app to the Play Store using this. It would simply be rejected. But I am not certain if that is the reason. I did not get the error message that you received. Instead, I received:

```
No AdResponse found, <message: /log> 
Bad request.
onFailedToReceiveAd(Invalid Ad request.)
```

This means that you are getting something from the server. So your request is being made correctly. Hence I did a little bit of research and found out that it is common for no ad to be returned for the first few times (there are quite a few answers in this forum that state this) and this problem seems to exist with the legacy SDK. So this could possibly be the reason. Outside of this, I cannot think of anything else. I have some theories but I would need to do some research before I am sure. Also, on a sidenote, you need to have:

```
ads:testDevices="your device id goes here" // one you get when you type adb devices
// this is to ensure that the services know you are simply testing and not using your own account to hit the service
```

In conclusion, I would suggest you migrate to the Google Play services Admob. I've only used it for practice before and learning purposes and it worked fine. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and for the time you give it to me. i still have the same probleme with those errors  
-JS: Uncaught ReferenceError: AFMA_getSdkConstants is not defined (about:blank:1)
-

Comment: can you add the full stacktrace of the error to your question. It looks like this is not a UI issue and is more of a logical error in the code.

Comment: unfortunately i cant post an image.
but i cant write those erreors :
-JS: Uncaught ReferenceError: AFMA_getSdkConstants is not defined (about:blank:1)
-Uncaught ReferenceError: AFMA_getSdkConstants is not defined:1
-

Comment: Are you running your code in an emulator or a device that is connected to the internet? Also, you are making the network requests in the background thread correct?

Comment: im running the code in a device connected to internet via wifi. is it possible that the adUnitId is not valide ?

Comment: Yes.. that is a possibility. It is in one of your AdView configurations that's off. I am unable to say for certain without looking at your backing code too.

Comment: how can i send you the codes. its impossible for me to post pictures her. can i use facebook to send you my code ?

Comment: you can use imgur.com to upload and then share the link in your question. I'm afraid I can't suggest facebook in this forum as it is against the rules. you can see other questions for example.

Comment: http://www.mediafire.com/download/wbo6yev8taij9bk/ProxyWebList.rar

this is my entire code. thank you for the time you are giving to me

Comment: I have to run this code when I get home. No AS installed in my current work machine... I'll update you with my findings later today

Comment: Im so greatful for you brother. u will save me

Comment: I have edited my answer with what I found. I think that was the root cause of your problem.

Comment: Hey brother. i think everythink was fine and only the adView couldnt load the ads in a short time. iv migrated my project to Google Play service and now its working perfectly. Thank yoi @Sunil